# Setting up bridged networks for KVM?

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I so I am very new to servers and I am trying to setup a KVM on mine. I am following [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-kvm-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server/) tutorial and I am confused about my interfaces file (I already backed it up). Mine currently has this in it:

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports enol
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Anyway I do not see the eth1 so I used enol instead is this correct? Also my server now when booting says "A start job is running for raise network interfaces" and takes about 5 minutes to boot. Based on that I haven't continued on with the installation of the KVM as I am not sure if I set up the bridge correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to Setup bridged networks for KVM ?

- Back up your netowork configuration with :

  `cp /etc/network/interface /etc/network/interface-of-backup`

***NOTE: Server environment needs a static IP Address, I've read where people use DHCP to
configure KVM Server, I only recommend a Static IP Address for your server.***

Adjust your network interface file as follows: ***NOTE replace eth0 with your NIC***

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#Set your NIC to manual.
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

#Set up your bridge br0 or xenbr0
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0  inet static
  address AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
  netmask EEE.EEE.EEE.FFF
  gateway AAA.BBB.CCC.GATE
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 1
  bridge_hello 2
  bridge_maxage 12
```

Save this config and reboot.

#### Do I need a static IP Address for my Server?

Note:
If your Server is behind a firewall on a LAN Network with a private IP address ( static e.g 192.168.0.254 router leased dynamically or manually configured ) you don't need a static IP from your Internet Service Provider.

**Configure your router**

- Configure your router to lease a reserved static IP address to your *Server*;
  which can be done by login into your *Router* via web browser using Server's gateway IP Address
  `http://gateway-ip-here.` or by using console.
- You can also configure your Server to have a static IP address on the *same
  network of your gateway* manually. This can be done by update Server network config file `/etc/network/interface` with preferred network configuration.

If your *Server's* IP Address when you do `ifconfig` is the same as your Internet IP Address when you type `what is my ip?` on google, if your result changes *then you have to
contact your ISP and request for a static IP Address for your Server.*

### Why do I need a static IP address ?

Your Server serves connected clients through services running on your server. For any client to connect to your server, it must be configured with your Server IP address manually or dynamically.

- Your web server is a service running on your server providing
  information to 100's of connected clients such as web browser world wide.
- Office Telephone lines are clients connected to PBX running on your
  Server.
- Network Printer, NFS and other Network Devices are connected to your server.

If your Server IP is not a Static IP, every time that your Server IP address dynamically changed. All connected client(s) or services will loose their connection until re-configured manually or automatically.

Comment: Hmm alright. Would reserving a IP on my home firewall work? And then using that IP as the static one? I don't have a static IP to use due to my internet provider not offering that unless I get a business account which is too expensive (This is meant to be a home learning server).

Comment: @RobertHarbison I answered your question in my edited answer.

Comment: @RobertHarbison you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats correct. The interface name may differ, but the name always points to physical NIC. It can be eth0, eno1 or whatever.